# How to word wrap UIWebView when zoomed?

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiwebview

I am trying to word wrap my html string when zoomed. I have set scalePagesToFit=YES and added a meta tag with device-width. But still i have to pan to see the hidden content. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML code for iOS 5.1

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name='viewport' 
          content='initial-scale=3.0, 
          minimum-scale=3.0, 
          maximum-scale=3.0, 
          user-scalable=no'>
  </head>
  <body>Stack Overflow<br>iOS 5.1</body>
</html>
```